# Magento 2 - After imported products - Can not show in frontend

Tags: magento2, product, import

I have problem: After imported products - all imported products did not show in frontend. Anyone know me step by step.

Comment: did you tried reindexing ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes!
I ran this command:

```
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

It worked !

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Please describe detail to your problem.

Comment: Its work for me after php bin/magento cache:flush